# Буквенное наращение после цифр

Tags: числительные, наращение

Скажите, пожалуйста, какой из этих вариантов правильный?

1) 2 въезд Иоасафа Белгородского;
2) 2-й въезд Иоасафа Белгородского;
3) 2-ой въезд Иоасафа Белгородского.

Answer (score 1):

Второй вариант правильный:

***2-й въезд Иоасафа Белгородского***

Ещё правильнее было бы словом: *второй*.

Наращение (буквенное падежное окончание) используется в записи порядковых числительных (отметаем вариант № 1).

Падежные наращения никогда и ни за что не начинаются с гласных (отметаем вариант № 3).

---

См.: ***[Когда нужны буквенные наращения после цифр?](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/87-rubric-99)***

Answer (score 1):

Наращение падежного окончания в порядковых числительных, обозначенных арабскими (1, 2, 3, 4...) цифрами, может быть однобуквенным или двухбуквенным.
По закрепившейся традиции наращение должно быть однобуквенным, если последней букве числительного предшествует гласный звук:

1-я Тверская-Ямская улица
1-я Брестская улица
2-й Иртышский проезд
2-й Сыромятнический переулок
**2-й въезд П. Осипенко** (Элиста)
3-й Самотёчный переулок
3-й Крутицкий переулок

Правильно так: **2-й въезд Иоасафа Белгородского.**

[**Буквенные окончания (наращения) числительных**](http://www.primavista.ru/blog/2017/01/06/narashheniya-chislitelnyih/)